# Does it make sense to plot impulse response functions for insignificant variables in Granger-causality tests?

Tags: vector-autoregression, granger-causality, impulse-response

I have 4 endogenous variables: call them w, x, y, and z. I am interested in the reduced form VAR where w is the dependent variable. Having run Granger tests, I found that only x and y Granger-cause w at a certain significance level.

Given that z is not found to Granger-cause w, can we infer anything meaningful by plotting an IRF where the impulse variable is z and the response variable is w?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see any problem doing that? Granger Causality test can be to harsh sometimes. Even if it is insignificant doesn't mean that there is no effect in the IRF function or any interesting conclusion to be taken the IRF output.